# How to refer the figure name in matlab

Tags: matlab

I would like to define a figure and then for that specific figure do some things. Foe example: I would like to vreat a digure say:

```
h1 = figure('units','normalized','outerposition',[0 0 1 1]);
```

and then I want for h1 to do for example:

```
subplot(1,3,1)
 plot(N_vec,1./Err(N_vec),sprintf('*%c',colconds(loop)),'LineWidth',5)
 hold on
 plot(N_vec,1./ErrPV(N_vec),sprintf('*%c',colconds(loop+2)),'LineWidth',5)
 hold on
 xlabel('Population size','fontsize',20)
 ylabel('Error^-2 ','fontsize',20)
 legend('OLE','PV','OLE shuffled','PV shuffled','Location','northwest')
```

The thing is that from loop reasons, h1 is defined far from the above lines. and is not the current figure handel. So I want the above lines to refer specifically for h1. somethong like:

```
subplot('h1',1,3,1)
   plot('h1',N_vec,1./Err(N_vec),sprintf('*%c',colconds(loop)),'LineWidth',5)
   hold on
   plot('h1',N_vec,1./ErrPV(N_vec),sprintf('*%c',colconds(loop+2)),'LineWidth',5)
   hold on
   xlabel('h1','Population size','fontsize',20)
   ylabel('h1','Error^-2 ','fontsize',20)
   legend('h1','OLE','PV','OLE shuffled','PV shuffled','Location','northwest')
```

But matlab gives error whenever i try to add the name h1 in the specific commands for the figure...

how do I refer the figure handel when I actully want to use it?

Thanks!!

Comment: Did you actually look at the help for `figure`? http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/figure.html   There is a very simple answer, but I'm not going to post it. You must learn to debug/check the help by yourself before asking SO.

Comment: @Royi I will. Thanks

Comment: @nkjt Yes i did. where excactly they refer there for figures that were defined far ago??

Comment: In the description to what `figure(h)` does... does that not ring any bells? Did the fact they don't use quotes to reference existing figures not give you a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could assign a `'Name'` or `'Tag'` to the h1 figure and then use that as a reference to get it before plotting.

```
% Create a figure with tag 'MyFig'
figure('Tag', 'MyFig');  

% ... later in the code ...

% Get the figure with the Tag "MyFig"
h1 = findobj('Type', 'Figure' ,'Tag', 'MyFig')
```

*Tag* is for this purpose better than *Name* as the later is shown after the figure number. The Type-Figure argument could be skipped, but narrows down the objects to search.

Now you can use `h1` as a regular handle.

```
subplot(h1,1,3,1)
plot(h1, ...)
```

You could also set `h1` figure to the current figure

```
set(groot, 'CurrentFigure', h1);
% ... or for older versions
set(0, 'CurrentFigure', h1)
```

Then you could omit the handle in the plot commands

```
subplot(1,3,1)
plot(...)
```